# Blender render (cycles) animation slows down midway. What causes this and do I depend on the new time per frame?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, timeline

My render started off as 2mins per frame, slowed down to 5mins and now it’s 11mins.
I have moving metaballs in the scene that enlarge overtime. Perhaps this is the cause of slowing down significantly?

Right now it’s 11 mins per frame. Is it going to stay this way?

Comment: its been 2 hrs , till now , has it finished , if yess , you got your awnsere

Answer (score 0):

The render time on each frame depends on the content of the scene at that particular frame. So it is normal that render times vary, if the complexity changes throughout the scene.

Answer (score 0):

The rendering time relies on couple things:

1. How many objects show up in the camera view, since the camera has clipping frustum.
2. How many lights in the scene, since the cycles are using ray tracing as PBR rendering technique.
3. What are the materials you are using for different objects.
4. Anti-aliasing, the level of anti-aliasing you are using impacts.
5. Shadow Volume.
6. Denoising, this is quite new to cycles, the phase happens in each rendering parallel sub section.